# php convert european datetime to mysql datetime

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I've got an datetime string like this: `28-06-14 11:01:00`

That's European for day 28, month 6, year 2014...

I'm trying to convert it to `2014-06-28 11:01:00` so that I can insert it into a database with field type `datetime`.

I've tried multiple things like this:

```
$datumHolder = new DateTime($data['datum'], new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
$datum1 = $datumHolder -> format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$datum2 = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $data['datum']) ) );

$datum3 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d-:Hi:s', $data['datum']);
```

This is the output I get:

```
datum1: 2028-06-14 11:01:00
datum2: 1970-01-01
```

And I get an error for `datum3`:

```
echo "datum3: " . $datum3->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); . '<br />';
Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get this to work?

Comment: @Novocaine88, when i run that ( using your string, not the variable ) i get the same output: `2028-06-14 11:01:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$datum3` method is correct way, you just have invalid input format.

Use:

```
$datum3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y H:i:s', $data['datum']);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// $data['datum'] is '28-06-14 11:01:00'
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y H:i:s', $data['datum']);

// y is two digit representation of a year, while Y is full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works indeed. Unfortunate for you, Glavic was a couple of seconds earlier. But you'll get an up vote from me!

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('28-06-14 11:01:00');
$output = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo $output;
```

That will give you a hint or two ;)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.